# Is it possible to use mutators on array? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table like this:

```
@foreach($order->cart->items as $item)
<tr>
   <th scope="row"><a href="/{{ $item['code_cat'] }}/{{ $item['url_cat'] }}/{{ $item['prod_url'] }}"><img class="basketimg mr-1" src="/img/products/{{$item['img']}}"><span class="basket-prod-name">{{ $item->Short_Prod_Name() }}</span></a></th>
   <td class="text-center">
      <div class="prodcount">{{$item['qty']}}</div>
   </td>
   <td class="text-right">{{$item['cost']}}AZN</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And for the name, I want to use a murator to strip out the name that is too long.

Here is:

```
public function getShortProdNameAttribute()
  {
      return substr($this->name, 0, 10);
  }
```

Now how can I use it?

`$item['Short_Prod_Name']` doesn't work, this is the first time I try to use a mutator on an array. How can i do this?

P.S.In other questions, they wrote that it is better to use `casts`, but still, is the mutator applicable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `Laravel` convention, the `getShortProdNameAttribute()` mutator will resolve to the `short_prod_name` attribute:

```
$item->short_prod_name
```

Rememeber to append the additional attribute in the `Item` class:

```
protected $appends = ['short_prod_name']
```

Thusly, the full code snippet is as follows:

```
@foreach($order->cart->items as $item)
<tr>
   <th scope="row"><a href="/{{ $item['code_cat'] }}/{{ $item['url_cat'] }}/{{ $item['prod_url'] }}"><img class="basketimg mr-1" src="/img/products/{{$item['img']}}"><span class="basket-prod-name">{{ $item->short_prod_name }}</span></a></th>
   <td class="text-center">
      <div class="prodcount">{{$item['qty']}}</div>
   </td>
   <td class="text-right">{{$item['cost']}}AZN</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

---

An alternative solution to address our problem is to use  `Str::limit`:

```
@foreach($order->cart->items as $item)
<tr>
   <th scope="row"><a href="/{{ $item['code_cat'] }}/{{ $item['url_cat'] }}/{{ $item['prod_url'] }}"><img class="basketimg mr-1" src="/img/products/{{$item['img']}}"><span class="basket-prod-name">{{ Str::limit($item->name, 10) }}</span></a></th>
   <td class="text-center">
      <div class="prodcount">{{$item['qty']}}</div>
   </td>
   <td class="text-right">{{$item['cost']}}AZN</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Correct +1, was about so write the same :) - worth mentioning is the "casting" is used to convert a value to another data-type. But you just want to alter a string to another string.